# Nested Checkbox in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I need to build nested checkbox in lightning component, like the below image.

[image]

I tried to achieve this using **ul** and **li** tag but its not appearing like the image:

```
<lightning:layoutItem size="2">
            <ul>
                <li>
            <lightning:input type="checkbox" name="dentures" label="Dentures:"/>
                </li>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <lightning:input type="checkbox" name="upper" label="Upper"/>
                        <lightning:input type="checkbox" name="lower" label="Lower"/>
                        <lightning:input type="checkbox" name="partial" label="Partial"/>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
</lightning:layoutItem>
```

Comment: put it in a table, the tags you are using are for lists and will be displayed in a column

Comment: @TimWillis Thanks! It worked, please convert this comment to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LI and UL tags are for lists and will always be displayed in a column,

you can easily achieve the desired formatting using a table such as

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> checkbox1 </td>
<td> checkbox2 </td>
<td> checkbox3 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```